# How to pass Two templates in a same class based views

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am having one issue with the django template view.

I am having two urls

1) For Current User Profile

2) For His Team mates

urls.py

```
path('profile/', views.UserprofileIndex.as_view(), name='user-profile'),
path('profile/<int:pk>', views.TeamProfileIndex.as_view(), name='team-profile'),
```

It's views

```
class TeamProfileIndex(TemplateView):

template_name = 'accounts/profile/team_profile.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = dict()
    self.pk = self.kwargs.get("pk")
    try:
        user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.pk)
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        logger.error("Requested user profile not available")
        raise Http404
    teams = User.objects.all()
    context.update(
        {
            'user_profile': user_profile,
            'teams' : teams
        }
    )
    return context


class UserprofileIndex(TemplateView):

template_name = 'accounts/profile/index.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = dict()
    try:
        user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        logger.error("Requested user profile not available")
        raise Http404

    teams = User.objects.all
    context.update(
        {
            'user_profile': user_profile,
            'teams' : teams
        }
    )
    return context
```

In both views only one query is changing , that is 'user_profile'.

Is there any way to pass this in a single views to two diffrent html pages ?

I have tried following method

class UserprofileIndex(TemplateView):
    # template_name = 'accounts/profile/index.html'

```
def initialize(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.pk = None
    self.pk = kwargs.get('pk')

def get_template_names(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk:
        return 'accounts/profile/team_profile.html'
    else:
        return 'accounts/profile/index.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = dict()
    try:
        if self.pk:
            user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.pk)
        else:
            user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        logger.error("Requested user profile not available")
        raise Http404

    teams = User.objects.all()
    context.update(
        {
            'user_profile': user_profile,
            'teams' : teams
        }
    )
    return context
```

But its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work. But I would advise using DetailView

```
class UserProfile(TemplateView):
    """
    User profile view
    """
    user_profile = None
    template_name = 'accounts/profile/index.html'
    team_profile_template_name = 'accounts/profile/team_profile.html'

    def get_user_profile(self):
        """
        Get user
        """
        if not self.user_profile:
            user_profile_pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
            model, filter_kwargs = (UserProfile, dict(user=user_profile_pk)) \
                if user_profile_pk else (Profile, dict(user=self.request.user))
            self.user_profile = get_object_or_404(model, **filter_kwargs)
        return self.user_profile

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(dict(user_profile=self.get_user_profile(),
                            teams=User.objects.all()))
        return context

    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.kwargs.get('pk'):
            return [self.team_profile_template_name]
        return super().get_template_names()
```

Comment: But I am having two views

One is index.html and another one is team_profile.html

Comment: Oh now i will fix it

Comment: @Anoop I added getting templates. Your code has an error. He returned the template as a string. Django demands return list

Comment: I am learning python 

I feel that your codes having high standard , Because if I am wrote 5 lines of codes you implement it in one line 

Could you please help me to reach your standard

Comment: How this block will work 

        if not self.user_profile:
            user_profile_pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
            model, filter_kwargs = (UserProfile, dict(user=user_profile_pk)) \
                if user_profile_pk else (Profile, dict(user=self.request.user))
            self.user_profile = get_object_or_404(model, **filter_kwargs)
        return self.user_profile

Comment: I got it 

It is python ternary conditional operator, right

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use two template in signle class based view
Do something like this which i do for
DetailView

```
class PollDetail(DetailView):
model = Poll
context_object_name = "poll"
```

Instead mentioning template name in Class mention it in urls
ulrs.py

```
path("result/<pk>",PollDetail.as_view(template_name="results.html")),
 path("vote/<pk>",PollDetail.as_view(template_name="vote.html"))
```